# jQuery remove <a> tag from certain sub class

Tags: jquery, html

I wanted to remove the `<a>` tag from certain classes. Here is my html:

```
<div class="my_class">
    <div class="sub_class">
        <p class="percent">0%</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="my_links_1">
            <p class="my_url"><a href="#">my link 1</a></p>
            <p class="my_url"><a href="#">my link 2</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub_class">
        <p class="percent">50%</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="my_links_2">
            <p class="my_url"><a href="#">my link 3</a></p>
            <p class="my_url"><a href="#">my link 4</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub_class">
        <p class="percent">50%</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="my_links_3">
            <p class="my_url"><a href="#">my link 5</a></p>
            <p class="my_url"><a href="#">my link 6</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub_class">
        <p class="percent">100%</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="my_links_4">
            <p class="my_url"><a href="#">my link 7</a></p>
            <p class="my_url"><a href="#">my link 8</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, what I wanted was to remove all the `<a>` tags except which percentage is 50%. I tried with this code, but it's removed all the `<a>` tags.

```
$.each($('.percent'), function (index, value) { 
    var per = $(value).text();
    if(per != "50%"){
        $(".my_url").find("a").contents().unwrap();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use appropriate `selector` for that: 
 Check the **below snippet**

```js
$('.percent').each(function() {
  var per = $(this).text();
  if (per != "50%") {
    $(this).parent('div').next().find(".my_url").find("a").contents().unwrap();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my_class">
  <div class="sub_class">
    <p class="percent">0%</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="my_links_1">
      <p class="my_url"><a href="#">my link 1</a>
      </p>
      <p class="my_url"><a href="#">my link 2</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub_class">
    <p class="percent">50%</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="my_links_2">
      <p class="my_url"><a href="#">my link 3</a>
      </p>
      <p class="my_url"><a href="#">my link 4</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub_class">
    <p class="percent">50%</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="my_links_3">
      <p class="my_url"><a href="#">my link 5</a>
      </p>
      <p class="my_url"><a href="#">my link 6</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sub_class">
    <p class="percent">100%</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="my_links_4">
      <p class="my_url"><a href="#">my link 7</a>
      </p>
      <p class="my_url"><a href="#">my link 8</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: one more question buddy! what will be the selector for this?

<tr>
 <td id="my_id_1" class="my_class">
  <table class="my_table_class" id="my_table_id">
   <tbody>
   <tr id="my_table_1" class="module">
    <td>Module 1</td>
    <td colspan="2">Module 1</td>         
   </tr>
   <tr class="unit">
    <td>Unit 1</td>
    <td class="my_unit"><a href="#">my link 1</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="unit">
    <td>Unit 2</td>
    <td class="my_unit"><a href="#">my link 2</a></td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </td>
</tr>

Comment: What you want to select here?

Comment: following the previous situation, just to remove <a> from here.